# Unterschied zwischen »leihen« und »ausleihen«

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   [*Difference between “leihen”, “ausleihen”, and “sich ausleihen”*](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25277/9551)

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "leihen" und "ausleihen?"  Beide bedeuten "to borrow" auf Englisch.

Comment: Es stimmt nicht, dass "leihen" und "ausleihen" beide auf Englisch "to borrow" heißen (oder bedeuten). Siehe die Antwort von T. Dittmar unten, siehe [Hallo, hier kommt Hermann](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH4YAgf4y8Y): "... e bissi was leiiihn" ;  Richtig ist aber, dass viele Deutsche irrtümlich "to borrow" sagen, wenn sie "to lend" meinen!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(1) Die beiden Verben *leihen* und *ausleihen* haben beide die identische Bedeutung "(gegen das Versprechen der Rückgabe) **vorübergehend** aus seinem Besitz zur Verfügung stellen".

Beispiele für diese erste Bedeutung sind:

- jemandem ein Buch leihen
- jemandem seine Aufmerksamkeit leihen (und sie dann wieder anderem zuwenden)
- jemandem sein Ohr leihen

(2) Daneben hat *leihen* eine weitere, gehobene Bedeutung, die *ausleihen* nicht hat, die schenkende **Überlassung**: "zuteilwerden lassen, geben, zur Verfügung stellen, eine Gunst gewähren".

Beispiele für diese zweite Bedeutung sind:

- jemandem seine Hilfe, seinen Beistand leihen
- jemandem seine Stimme leihen (bei einer Wahl)
- jemandem seine Stimme leihen (für jemanden eintreten)
- jemandem Kraft, Mut, Schutz usw. leihen ("Die Verzweiflung soll mir Kräfte leihn." Friedrich Wilhelm Gotter, "Merope")

*Meines Erachtens ist die Überlassung in der zweiten Bedeutung **dauerhaft** in dem Sinne, dass Hilfe, Stimme, Kraft usw. nicht zurückgenommen werden, sondern im Besitz des Empfängers verbleiben, bis die Umstände sich geändert haben (Bruch der Freundschaft, Neuwahl, Meinungsänderung, Unwürdigkeit, in der Reihenfolge der Beispiele). Die Rückforderung bei der ersten Bedeutung ist implizit, automatisch und unabhängig von den Umständen. Ein nachträglicher Verzicht auf die Rückforderung oder eine nachträgliche Umwandlung der Leihgabe in ein Geschenk ändern nichts an der ursprünglichen Intention.*

Quelle: Duden, DWDS, Grimm

Comment: Gute Beispiele für Dauerhaftigkeit sind das aber nicht. Weder meine Aufmerksamkeit noch meine Hilfe verleihe ich dauerhaft. Richtig aber ist, dass es Beispiele sind, wo *ausleihen* nicht nutzbar ist – ob das immer gilt, wenn etwas nicht Gegenständliches verliehen wird?

Comment: Gibst du die Hilfe zurück, oder darfst du sie behalten?

Comment: Ist diese Frage noch philosophisch oder schon pseudophilosophisch? So oder so nicht die Art von Frage, die ich beantworten müssen möchte, bevor ich weiß, ob ich *leihen* oder *ausleihen* nutzen kann.

Comment: Redewendungen wie "Liebe schenken" oder "Hilfe leihen" machen ein recht gegenständliches Verständnis interpersonalen Handelns deutlich. Liebe wird als etwas durchaus Konkretes erlebt, das die Empfänger dann im Besitz haben: "Ich trage deine Liebe in mir" ist eine feststehende Wendung. Meine Gegenfrage war also keineswegs philosophisch sondern ganz und gar linguistisch gemeint. Dass weder Aufmerksamkeit noch Liebe ewig währen, widerlegt nicht diesen "Besitzwechsel": man gibt sie ja in der Regel nicht zurück, sondern "verliert" sie -- und verlieren kann man nur, was man bis dato dauerhaft hatte.

Comment: Es liegt aber in der Natur dieser Vergegenständlichungen, dass sie nicht untereinander konsistent zu sein brauchen: Wenn ich jemandem mein Herz ausschütte, kann mir danach immer noch ein Stein von diesem fallen und jemand, den ich darin eingeschlossen habe, wird es weiterhin bleiben. Und über verschiedene Kulturen kann die Vergegenständlichung noch deutlich krasser variieren. Eine solche Vergegenständlichung – außer als Sprachspielerei – weiterzudenken entbehrt jeder Grundlage. Genau das verlangst Du aber von demjenigen, der Deine Erklärung nutzen soll.

Comment: Das Verständnis von Liebe und Zuwendung als gegenständlich ist keine Metapher wie der Stein, der vom Herzen fällt, sondern eine Empfindung. Ich denke aber, dass du recht hast, dass Dauerhaftigkeit das Wesentliche an der zweiten Bedeutung nicht erfasst, und habe meine Antwort entsprechend verändert.

Comment: Es werden Orden und Preise verliehen, die nicht zurückgefordert werden, sowie bei Wahlen Stimmen, die aber nur eine Wahlperiode Gültigkeit haben.

Comment: Danke, "jemandem seine Stimme leihen" ist ein sehr gutes Beispiel. Preise VERleihen passt hier nicht so recht.

Comment: ist vielleicht etwas spät, aber ich habe "Hilfe leihen" noch nie gehört und finde es extrem komisch eben weil man sie ja nicht wiederhaben will/kann

Comment: Ich habe auch vieles noch nie gehört, was im Duden steht. Schau mal dort unter "leihen".

Comment: Ach, und die bei der Wahl verliehenen Stimmen sind durchaus dauerhaft in dem Sinne, dass sie gelten, solange die Umstände Bestand haben. Auch das Buch, das ich dir schenke, überdauert nur solange, bis du es verlierst oder dein Haus abbrennt. Deswegen würdest du aber nicht die Dauerhaftigkeit des Geschenks in Frage stellen.

Comment: Statt 2x *"Stimme"* könnte man auch noch sein *"Ohr/Gehör"* leihen... ;)

Comment: Ich finde das Kriterium der Dauerhaftigkeit bzgl. der zweiten Gruppe immer noch wenig hilfreich, zumal keines der Worte *zuteilwerden lassen, geben, zur Verfügung stellen, eine Gunst gewähren* Dauerhaftigkeit impliziert. Das *geliehene Ohr* ist ein gutes Gegenbeispiel. Wie soll hier ernsthaft jemand mit dem obigen Entscheidungskriterium zum richtigen Schluss kommen? Bisher ist die mangelnde Gegenständlichkeit das deutlich bessere Kriterium.

Answer (score 5):

*leihen* can be used in some formal contexts, in which *ausleihen* is not used. On the other hand, whenever you can use *ausleihen,* you can also use *leihen.* As a rule of thumb, whenever a fee or another price for borrowing something is paid, you can only use *leihen.* In any case, both words can describe both, the active and the passive process:

> Ich leihe [mir] das Buch [aus]. (I borrow the book.)
>   Ich leihe meinem Freund das Buch [aus]. (I lend the book to my friend.)

A few examples in which *ausleihen* would not be used are bank loans, car rentals or land tenures. Note that *ausleihen* can always be used for borrowing a book from a library, since the process of borrowing is (at least in Germany) free – even if there are library membership fees or late fees.

Comment: Wenn ich kurz nach München jette, dann kann ich mir dort ein Auto ausleihen, nicht? Ganz unabhängig von der Frage, ob ich dafür zahle oder oder nicht. Gegen eine kleine Gebühr würde ich Dir auch einen USB-Stick ausleihen. [Quelle 1](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung&lemid=DA04278), [Quelle 2](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GA08469), [Quelle 3](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=GWB&lemid=JA05791).

Comment: Ich glaube auch das es da im wesentlichen keine Regeln gibt für (aus)leihen/borgen.... jeder wie er Bock hat.

Comment: @user unknown: Wenn du *jettest*, bewegst Du Dich eh nicht mehr in der Standardsprache der Gegenwart, genausowenig wie Deine Links es tun. USB-Sticks werden hierzulande nicht kommerziell verliehen, insofern mindert es die angegebene Faustregel nicht. Zur Untermauerung meiner Abgrenzung: [1](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Auto+leihen%2C+Auto+ausleihen%2C+Wagen+leihen%2CWagen+ausleihen&year_start=1970&corpus=20), [2](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Geld+leihen%2C+Geld+ausleihen&year_start=1970&corpus=20) (obwohl ich das alles auch von meinen Eltern leihen kann).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Hättest Du "jetten" bei Google-NGram eingegeben, dann wüsstest Du, wie falsch Du liegst. Zweitens steht es mir frei USB-Sticks kommerziell zu verleihen, das garantiert mir die Berufsfreiheit. Unabhängig davon könnte es Bestandteil einer fiktionalen Erzählung sein. Deine Links zeigen zwar, dass Geld leihen häufiger ist als ausleihen (wobei "wir leihen uns Geld aus" eben wohl als "leihen" und nicht als "ausleihen" gezählt wird), aber eben nicht "you can only use" - im Gegenteil dementiert Dein Link Deine Behauptung eindrucksvoll.

Comment: @user unknown: Habe das Ngram gesehen, und wüsste nicht wieso es widerlegt, dass [*jetten*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jetten) Umgangssprache ist. Eine Faustregel ist eben nur eine Faustregel und muss erst recht keine fiktiven Fälle abdecken. Im Ngram ist »wir leihen uns Geld aus« überhaupt nicht erfasst, da die Wortfolge »Geld leihen« nicht enthalten ist. Schließlich ist auch kein »you can only use« zu erwarten, da ich wie gesagt sowohl ein Auto als auch Geld ohne Gebühr leihen kann, z. B. von meinen Eltern.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Das war dann ein Mißverständnis. Ich dachte Du wirfst dem Gebrauch von "jetten" vor veraltet zu sein, nicht dass es Umgangssprache ist. Das ist sowieso unerheblich für Frage, da es ja um das Ausleihen eines Autos ging. Fahren wir also mit der Bahn nach München. Vielleicht bringst Du die Unterscheidung Leihe/Miete mit Leihe/Ausleihe http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leihvertrag durcheinander? Den Ngramvergleich hast Du übrigens angezettelt - das kannst Du mir schlecht anlasten.

Comment: @user unknown: Wo habe ich Dir die Ngrammität Deines Ngrams angelastet? Und nur dass die Justiz zwischen Miete und Leihe unterscheidet, heißt noch nicht, dass es der Rest der Menschheit auch tut: Die Dienste einer Autovermietung werden sprachlich auch mit *leihen* bezeichnet, aber meiner Erfahrung nach eben nicht mit *ausleihen.*

Comment: Ich würde auch im privaten Umfeld nicht davon sprechen mir Geld auszuleihen. Ausleihen impliziert für mich dass ich denselben Gegenstand zurückgebe, das ist bei Geld typischerweise nicht der Fall. (Auch nicht bei Eiern oder Milch von den Nachbarn. Borgen passt hier besser, leihen geht glaube ich auch, ausleihen nach meinem Gefühl nicht.)

Answer (score 5):

Falsch - *leihen* ist *to borrow*, wenn Du Dir **von** jemandem etwas (aus)leihst. Wenn Du jemand anderem etwas (aus)leihst, dann heißt es im Englischen *to lend*.

Answer (score 2):

Das Englische ist hier sehr viel klarer als das Deutsche. In diesem Fall (bei weitem nicht in allen) zeigt schon die phonetische Verwandtschaft, dass "to borrow" zu "borgen" gehört mit der Bedeutung  "etwas vorübergehend in Besitz nehmen" und "to lend" dem deutschen "leihen" mit der komplementären Bedeutung "jemandem etwas vorübergehend zur Verfügung stellen" entspricht. Man kann das z.B. auch daran erkennen, dass es einen Auto- und Filmverleih gibt, aber keinen Verborg.

Da ich aber offensichtlich nicht der einzige bin, der hier immer nachdenken muss, sind die beiden Begriffe im Deutschen gehörig durcheinandergekommen. Man sagt "Ich leih mir schnell was" und "Ich borg es dir", die entsprechenden Präfixe "aus-", "her-" und "ver-" (-borgen oder -leihen) machen sie zu Synonymen, bei denen die restlichen Satzteile und ihre grammatischen Formen die Bedeutungsarbeit leisten. In sehr hochsprachlichen Texten würde ich trotzdem die ursprünglichen Bedeutungszuordnungen beibehalten.

Sorry, because of the many comments in German I didn't recognize the question was in English. And sorry again that I didn't quite cover your question:

At least in colloquial German, "borgen" and "leihen" more or less have become synonyms whose meanings depend on prefixes and the context of allocated subjects and objects. In the case of "leihen" and "ausleihen" to me the more general use seems to be nowadays:

> leihen = to lend (the classical meaning: Ich leihe dir mein Auto)
>
> ausleihen = to borrow (Darf ich mir dein Auto ausleihen?)

But, as both are subject to colloquial use, you could as well hear:

> Ich leihe mir schnell dein Auto (borrow)
>
> Leihst du mir dein Auto aus? (lend; not common in Austria)

Comment: I can't recognize a better clarity in English. lend=*verleihen*; borrow=*ausleihen* and  *leihen* as a ambiguous word shifting the giving or receiving role to the context.