# Der Unterschied zwischen "borgen" und "ausleihen"

Tags: grammar, verb, verb-usage

> Du kannst das Fahrrad von meinem Bruder borgen.
>
> Du kannst das Fahrrad von meinem Bruder ausleihen.

Kann man die beiden Verben wahlweise verwenden?

Comment: Related: [Unterschied zwischen »leihen« und »ausleihen«](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6356/9551)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das sind bedeutungsgleiche Synonyme, und sie können auch gleich verwendet werden:

> Martin borgt sich einen Bleistift von Walter.
>   Martin leiht sich einen Bleistift von Walter aus.
>
> Walter borgt Martin seinen Bleistift.
>   Walter leiht Martin seinen Bleistift aus.

In den genannten Beispielen kann man »ausleihen« auch durch »leihen« ersetzen:

> Martin leiht sich einen Bleistift von Walter.
>   Walter leiht Martin seinen Bleistift.

Aber auch die Variante mit »ausleihen« ist nicht falsch (in den genannten Beispielen aber unüblich). 
Der [Unterschied zwischen »leihen« und »ausleihen«](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6356/1487) wurde bereits in einer separaten Frage behandelt.

Comment: Ich stimme zwar grundsätzlich und vor allem als Verwendungshinweis für DAFler zu, aber _borgen_ kann für mich eher als _(aus)leihen_ auch die Aspekte ‚ungefragt‘ (also Scheindiebstahl mit Rückgabeabsicht) und ‚dauerhaft/verbrauchend‘ (z.B. Papiertaschentuch, Windel oder Zigarette, wo der Gefallen evtl. zukünftig erwidert wird) haben. Letzteres heißt regional bspw. auch _schnorren_ oder _bühlen_.

Comment: @Crissov: »Bühlen« ist mir gänzlich unbekannt. »Schnorren« hat in Österreich eine sehr ähnliche Bedeutung wie »betteln«: Man bittet um etwas, ohne die Absicht zu haben es zurückzugeben oder eine andere Gegenleistung zu erbringen. "Betteln" wird verwendet, wenn fremde bitten, "schnorren", wenn es Bekannte tun. Wenn der Bürokollege gerade nicht da ist, und man von seinem Schreibtisch einen Kugelschreiber nimmt, mit der Absicht ihn später wieder zurückzugeben, dann ist das in Österreich sowohl "(aus)leihen" als auch "(aus)borgen". Diese Wörter sind also auch in diesem Fall Synonyme.

Comment: _Bühlen_ habe ich auch erst im Rheinland kennengelernt. _Schnorren_, von dem ich dachte es sei norddeutsch, sehe ich ähnlich, denn bei einem Bekannten, der sich etwas schnorrt, schnorrt man sich vielleicht auch manchmal oder zukünftig etwas. Die Kompensation ist also nicht die Rückgabe, sondern der implizit versprochene Ersatz bei Bedarf.

Comment: "Borgen" würde ich immer negativ sehen, wenn auch nicht so negativ wie "stehlen". Borgen ist das ungefragte nehmen von Dingen und gerade geborgte Kleinigkeiten werden in der Regel nicht zurück gegeben (siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_Fall_f%C3%BCr_die_Borger).

Comment: @Iris: Das ungefragte sich nehmen von Dingen, die anderen gehören, ist aber Stehlen.

Comment: @userunknown, stehlen ist meiner Meinung nach immer heimlich und die stehlende Person beabsichtigt die gestohlene Sache nicht zurückzugeben. Wenn sich nun aber jemand meinen Radiergummi borgt, dann ist das nicht heimlich und warhscheinlich sehe ich ihn nie wieder. Ich gehe zwar davon aus, dass der andere beabsichtigt ihn mir zurückzugeben, aber es wird wahrscheinlich vergessen oder der nächste den Radiergummi borgt sich ihn, so, dass er irgenwann einfach verschwindet.

Comment: @Iris: Wenn es nicht heimlich ist, und der andere nicht protestiert, dann ist es wohl Borgen. Die Frage muss dabei nicht ausgesprochen werden, sondern kann nonverbal ein Augenkontakt sein. Wenn der Kollege nicht da ist, und man nimmt etwas mit und hinterlässt keine Nachricht - kommt drauf an, ob man darauf vertraut, ob der andere sowohl die Erlaubnis erteilt hätte, auch für das ungefragte Ausborgen.

Comment: @userunknown Im juristischen Sinne schließt "Diebstahl" eine "Zueignungsabsicht" ein, die bloße Wegnahme einer fremden Sache in der Absicht sie zurückzugeben ist (zumindest juristisch) kein Diebstahl.

Answer (score 4):

Ein Unterschied zwischen borgen und leihen ist, dass leihen umgangssprachlich auch Fälle mit Leihgebühr umfassen kann.

"Ein Fahrrad borgen" impliziert, dass es kostenlos ist,
"Ein Fahrrad leihen" kann auch kostenlos sein, muss aber nicht (Fahrradverleih mit Leihgebühr).

Dieser Fahrradverleih verborgt nicht, umgangssprachlich verleiht er, offiziell vermietet er.

Die umgangssprachliche "Leihgebühr" ist aber so verbreitet, dass sie z.B. in Zeitungen lt. [DWDS etwa gleichoft wie "Hundesteuer"](https://www.dwds.de/r/plot?view=3&norm=abs&smooth=spline&genres=1&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1900%3A2016&q1=Leihgeb%C3%BChr&q2=Hundesteuer) auftaucht.

Nachdem @HubertSchölnast den Unterschied zu den offiziellen/legalen Begriffen aufgebracht (für D siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leihvertrag_(Deutschland)) hat, hier noch relevante offizielle Begriffe:

- Beim Leihen wird derselbe Gegenstand (nach Benutzung) zurückgegeben
- Wenn nur gleich(wertige) Rückgabe vorgesehen ist ("Borgst du mir ein Taschentuch, bekommst morgen eins zurück?"), dann ist das ein [Darlehen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlehen_(Deutschland)).

Comment: Wenn eine Gebühr verlangt wird, ist das (zumindest in Österreich) im juristischen Sinn keine Leihe, sondern eine Miete. Etwas, das im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch *Leihgebühr* genannt ist, ist rechtlich daher immer eine Miete. Ein kommerzieller *Fahrradverleih* ist also vor dem Gesetz ein Fahrzeugvermieter, auch wenn der allgemeine Sprachgebrauch ein anderer ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast:  das ist auch in Deutschland so https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leihvertrag_(Deutschland), aber Leihgebühr ist in der Umgangssprache verbreitet, z.B. http://www.rp-online.de/nrw/staedte/dormagen/fuer-cds-und-dvds-bezahlen-aid-1.111599. DWDS zählt (absolut) Leihgebühr in Zeitungen etwa so oft wie Hundesteuer.

Answer (score 2):

Die Wörter haben unterschiedliche regionale Verbreitung. Es mag ein grosses Gebiet geben, wo sie synonym verwendet werden, aber im Schweizer Hochdeutsch wird man *borgen* kaum antreffen, sondern nur *ausleihen* – nebst den Synonymen *auslehnen* oder *entlehnen* (die vielleicht ausserhalb der Schweiz weniger gebräuchlich sind?).

Comment: Ich glaube, *borgen* ist in keinem allemannischen oder schwäbischen Dialekt bekannt.

Answer (score 1):

Polonius (in Shakespeares Hamlet) belehrt seinen Sohn: "Neither a borrower nor a lender be", was Schlegel/Tieck übersetzen als "Sei kein Borger und auch Verleiher nicht". Da hat man also im Deutschen einen Unterschied ähnlich zumindest verstanden (passiver Sprachgebrauch), auch wenn man ihn beim Formulieren vielleicht auch schon damals nicht so scharf angewandt hat wie in England.

Comment: Es scheint mir, als ob Du hier *ver*leihen (=geben) mit *aus*leihen (=nehmen) verwechselst.

Answer (score -2):

Es sind auf keinen Fall Synonyme!

Sie beschreiben wer von wem etwas bekommt oder wer wem etwas gibt. Leihen beschreibt, dass etwas vorübergehend einer anderen Person gegeben wurde.

Borgen beschreibt, dass etwas vorübergehend von einer anderen Person genommen wurde.

Udo leiht Bernd Geld. Bernd borgt das Geld. Udo borgt es nicht..es gehört ja ihm.

Lend shows that something is (temporarily) given to another person. Borrow shows that something is (temporarily) taken from another person.

- lend ----> someone
- someone ----> borrow

- Wrong: I borrowed $10 to Jeff
- Right: I lent $10 to Jeff.

- Wrong: I lent $10 from Jeff.
- Right: I borrowed $10 from Jeff.

Comment: That's certainly correct for English, but for German I've never heard that distinction. It's always clarified by case (who lends something to whom,e.g., "ich habe es ihr geliehen") or preposition ("er hat es von ihr geliehen").

Comment: Nein, auf Deutsch gehen beide in beide Richtungen: Udo borgt Ute ein Taschentuch. Ute borgt Udos Taschentuch. Udo leiht Ute ein Taschentuch, Ute leiht Udos Taschentuch/von Udo ein Taschentuch.

Comment: Wenn ich (Subjekt) mir einen Hammer von meinem Nachbarn (Dativobjekt) borge, dann bekomme ich den Hammer meines Nachbarn. Wenn aber ich (Subj) meinem Nachbarn (Dat.obj.) einen Hammer borge, gebe ich meinen Hammer her. Borgen funktioniert also in beide Richtungen. Ebenso kann ich (Subj) mir einen Hammer vom Nachbarn (Dat.obj.) leihen (ich bekomme seinen Hammer), oder ich (Subj.) kann ihm (Dat.obj.) meinen Hammer leihen (ich gebe meinen Hammer her). Also funktioniert auch leihen in beide Richtungen. Und auch die Bedeutung ist dieselbe. Also sind *»borgen«* und *»leihen«* Synonyme.