# leihen VS ausleihen VS borgen (Fragen)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Sind diese Fragen richtig?

> Kann ich mir dein Buch **(aus)leihen** (/borgen)?
>
> Kannst du mir dein Buch **(aus)leihen** (/borgen)?
>
> Kann ich mir etwas Geld von dir **leihen** (/borgen)?
>
> Kannst du mir etwas Geld **leihen** (/borgen)?

Comment: Für die ersten zwei siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6356/unterschied-zwischen-leihen-und-ausleihen

Comment: yes, these examples are correct. for detailed differences please see linked question of mtwde.