# Was sind die Unterschiede zwischen leihen, ausleihen und entleihen?

Tags: difference

Wenn man ein Buch aus der Bibliothek ausleiht, kann man nicht "entleihen" verwenden? Zum Beispiel: "Er hat ein Buch aus der Bibliothek entliehen."

Bitte antworten Sie auf Deutsch, vielen Dank.

Comment: *Entleihen* ist gehobene Sprache, außer Bürokraten sagt das keiner.

Comment: Vgl *Lehen*, *Darlehen*. Vgl dazu eventuel korumpiert *entlehnen*, *ablehnen*, *ablösen* (vgl En *lease*), *erlösen*, *entlassen*, *verlegen*, *Verlag*, *Auslagen*, wobei *lage-* wie *Nagel* immer noch niederdeutsch *leie*, bzw *neil* entspricht (vgl En *lay*).

Comment: siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6356/unterschied-zwischen-leihen-und-ausleihen

Answer (score 4):

Der Unterschied zwischen *ausleihen* und *entleihen* ist sehr subtil.

> *Thomas* *hat* ein Buch aus der Bibliothek *ausgeliehen*.

Hier wird auf neutrale Weise berichtet, dass Thomas etwas ausgeliehen hat. Der Fokus liegt auf dem Akteur Thomas und seiner Tätigkeit des Ausleihens.

> Thomas *hat* *ein Buch* aus der Bibliothek *entliehen*.

Die Vorsilbe *ent-* kennzeichnet, dass durch die Haupttätigkeit etwas weggenommen oder *ent*nommen wurde. *Entleihen* trägt die Hauptbedeutung *ausleihen* und die Nebenbedeutung *entnehmen*, wodurch das Entnommene, in diesem Fall *ein Buch*, etwas mehr Gewicht bekommt. *Entleihen* ist demnach spezifischer als *ausleihen*. Das erklärt auch, wieso im Alltag eher *ausleihen* statt *entleihen* verwendet wird. Da spielt die Nebenbedeutung häufig keine Rolle.

Comment: OP wollte auch noch etwas zu 'leihen' erfahren - vielleicht ein Hinweis, dass man etwas (ver-)leihen kann, aber auch (aus-)leihen, gerade im normalen Sprachgebrauch nur über den Fall aufgeklärt: "Ich leihe _mir_ etwas (aus)" vs. "ich leihe _ihm_ etwas" (= "ich verleihe etwas an ihn")

Answer (score 1):

Es ist zwar eher unüblich zu sagen: "Ich entleihe ein Buch aus der Bibliothek." 
Normalerweise benützt man zumeist "ausleihen", wie zum Beispiel: "Ich leihe mir ein Buch aus der Bibliothek aus." 
Oder noch häufiger würde man sagen: "Ich leihe Bücher aus der Bibliothek."

Es handelt sich dabei allerdings einfach um den üblichen Sprachgebrauch, wie er sich eingebürgert hat. Möglich wären wohl alle drei Optionen.